# how to verify the integrity of binary downloaded from web to windows 10

Tags: security, signature, gnupg, pgp

I am trying to verify the integrity of Putty msi from their website ( not to say I don't trust it. Instead, just use it as a case study ).

On the website [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html), there are signature (.gpg file)  and public key (.asc file) for release package.
But what tool is available on Windows 10 to sign the msi using their own public key to generate a signature, then compare the generated signature against the one published on their websit.

I was trying to use Kleopatra. Which I just installed last night and generated a pair of keys for myself. Thus I am a bit struggling at how to instruct Kleopatra to sign the putty msi binary using their public key. ( I don't see the option to remove it).

It would be great if someone could point me a right direction or better tool.

Thanks,
Frank